# Scrapy: working correctly in debug mode with break point, and not correctly without a break point

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy

I have a Python3 code that uses Scrapy.
When I put a breakpoint inside the `def parse(self, response):` then the code works as expected. But if I run it without a break-point in normal mode it is not doing what it is supposed to do.
**Is there any timing** issue that should be aware of?

Here is part of my code:

```
import scrapy
...
class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'example.com'
    allowed_domains = ['example.com']
    start_urls = [
        'http://www.example.com/1.html',
        'http://www.example.com/2.html',
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        ...
        image_link = self.get_image_link(response)
        try:
            item = response.xpath("//*[@id='theid1']").extract_first()
        except:
            item = response.xpath("//*[@id='theid2']").extract_first()
        ...
        tmp = 1
```

When I put a breakpoint at `image_link = self.get_image_link(response)` then when I run the code step by step, I see that `item` has some values. But if I put a breakpoint at `tmp=1` I see that `item` is `None`. Also if I run the code without a breakpoint I don't get the expected result which shows me `item` is `None`.
The `image_link = self.get_image_link(response)` is just finding the URL of an image on the website.

What could be the issue and how to get the expected result without running the code in debug mode?

Comment: Have you tried `sleep` or something that will behave like you're stopping on the breakpoint?

Comment: Yes I tried sleep and no matter how long it doesn't help.

Comment: first of all `response.xpath("//*[@id='theid1']").extract_first()` will not raise an exception even the element not found, it just return `None`, so `"//*[@id='theid2']"` never run. Since the order of response from `start_urls` depends on download time, I suspect when you add breakpoint, `1.html` back first, item will not be `None`, otherwise get `None`, please try replace `try except` with `if else` and see.

Comment: @stasdeep Fantastic explanation and response. Looks like what you said is correct and it resolves my issue. If you want please put it in an answer so I can accept it. Thank you so much.

Comment: @TJ1 do you mean my response resolves your issue. :-)

Comment: @stasdeep yes it did :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pennyliangliping just commented and didn't put his comment in an answer, I will put his comment here as an answer so it helps others who have similar issue:

first of all

```
response.xpath("//*[@id='theid1']").extract_first()
```

will not raise an exception even the element not found, it just return None, so `//*[@id='theid2']` never runs. Since the order of response from start_urls depends on download time, I suspect when you add breakpoint, 1.html back first, item will not be None, otherwise get None, please try replace try except with if else and see.